# How to fix a currency symbol to the price box in an email form

Tags: html, email

I have searched for an answer to this. But as I understand it we cannot add questions onto somebody else's questions.

I want to add the $ sign to a price field in an email form, such that any input to the form would come after the $ sign, which should be the leftmost entry in the input box, before the figure amount. It shouldn't be outside the input box. And should be an integral part of the price field.

I'm not an expert, and couldn't really understand the various suggestions. The simplest one which caught my eye was the suggestion if I'm using bootstrap. Which I am. So my question is, How would I alter this code to achieve what I want.

```
<div class="row half">
.
.
<div class="3u"><input type="text" name ="price" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/', '', $_GET['price']); ?>"/></div>
</div>
```

If not the bootstrap solution. How else would I edit this to get the same effect?

Comment: <div class="row half">
<div class="3u"><input type="text" name ="price" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/', '', $_GET['price']); ?>"/></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boostrap you can create an input with the dollar sign preceding using input groups as follows

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input name ="price" placeholder="Price" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/', '', $_GET['price']); ?>">
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline